# Fetch failed loading: POST "http://localhost:3000/weather"

Tags: javascript

Terminal Error:

```js
> weather-app@1.0.0 devStart
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
node:events:355
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1310:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1358:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1445:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/ivan-ilyich/Documents/dev/weather-app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ivan-ilyich/Documents/dev/weather-app/server.js:22:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1337:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
^C
ivan-ilyich@ivan-Ilyich:~/Documents/dev/weather-app$ kill
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
ivan-ilyich@ivan-Ilyich:~/Documents/dev/weather-app$ stop

Command 'stop' not found, but there are 18 similar ones.

ivan-ilyich@ivan-Ilyich:~/Documents/dev/weather-app$ npm stop devStart
npm ERR! missing script: stop

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ivan-ilyich/.npm/_logs/2021-02-26T14_02_05_736Z-debug.log
ivan-ilyich@ivan-Ilyich:~/Documents/dev/weather-app$ ^C
ivan-ilyich@ivan-Ilyich:~/Documents/dev/weather-app$ ^C
ivan-ilyich@ivan-Ilyich:~/Documents/dev/weather-app$ npm run devStart

> weather-app@1.0.0 devStart
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
node:events:355
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1310:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1358:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1445:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/ivan-ilyich/Documents/dev/weather-app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ivan-ilyich/Documents/dev/weather-app/server.js:22:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1337:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I'm new to programming and maybe my question is silly but I didn't found an answer from similar questions so I'll give it a try and post my own(sorry for my bad English, it's not my native language).
I'm working on a small tutorial weather app project but I'm forced to make it "my" way and I'm lost with the connection of the server and the client.
I keep getting that error: Fetch failed loading: "http://localhost:3000/weather"

Client side:

```js
const searchElement = document.querySelector('[data-city-search]')
const searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(searchElement)

searchBox.addListener('places_changed', () => {
    const place = searchBox.getPlaces()[0]
    if (place == null) {
        return
    }
    const latitude = place.geometry.location.lat()
    const longitude = place.geometry.location.lng()
    fetch('/weather', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude
        })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        // setWeatherData(data, place.formatted_address)
    })
})
```

Server side:

```js
if ( process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ) {
    require('dotenv').config()
}

const OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY = process.env.OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const axios = require('axios')

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.post('/weather', (req, res) => {
    const url = `api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${req.body.lat}&lon=${req.body.lon}&appid=${OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY}`
    axios({
        url: url,
        responseType: 'json'
    })
    .then(data => res.json(data.main))
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server Started!');
})
```

[image: NEW ERROR]

Comment: The error makes it seem that your server is not actually started (or it may have crashed). Are you starting the server manually e.g., with `node`, and if so, any clues in the output from that terminal?

Comment: I think you have to add protocol (http(s)://) to `api.openweathermap.org`

Comment: actually I don't think it's with fetch.. could you tell me what `localhost/:1` is when you click the error? I believe that error causes a chain reaction

Comment: @MykWillis I'm starting my server with "npm start", the server starts and when I type a location in google searchBox, it finds the location but it crashes as soon as I hit enter and make the request, throwing that error in the console "node:internal/process/promises:227
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

<ref *1> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1137:16)"   followed by an object and at the end it throws this: [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: @MaximMazurok I tried that as soon as I've read your comment but it didn't work

Comment: @TheBombSquad when I click the localhost/:1, it shows me the Source, I open script.js and it throws that error at the start of the second argument of fetch " 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED "

Comment: then I have one request.. could you edit your question to show the error happening server side?

Comment: @TheBombSquad Yeah offcourse, I've added the terminal error, and at the very last lines I see two properties:   response: undefined,
                                              isAxiosError: true,

Comment: `?lat=#${req.body.latitude}&lon=$` why is there a `#` before lat and not lon parameters? Is it a documented way for this API to use `#` in the URL? Seems like the error could be that.

Comment: Are you sure you are sending request to rigth port? Because your server is running on port 3000 and you are sending request to 80

Comment: @AbrarHossain Yes you're right about the # sing, I've fixed it, but it didn't cause the net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error

Comment: @barbarbar338  Yeah maybe that's causing the error, I'm trying to find a way to change the port right now

Answer (score 2):

Just change `fetch('/weather', {` as `fetch('http://localhost:3000/weather', {`
You are hosting your api on port 3000 and trying to send a POST request to port 80

Comment: and double check whether it should be `POST`.In my view, it can be `GET`

Comment: @barbarbar338 Thank you so much! It doesn't throw an error anymore, I really appreciate it

Comment: @barbarbar338 I'm sorry but I didn't saw it right away, the server now crashes before it even start throwing  that error: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000

Comment: you are running more than one instances on same port (which is port 3000 in this case)

Comment: I've killed the server manually, run npm start devStart, the server started but now any time I try to make a request I get a new error, I will upload it with an image, I don't know what I'am doing so wrong, maybe it's time to start the project from scratch, I really don't know what to do